# php explode by comma ignore thousands seperator

Tags: php, regex, explode

I am scraping the following kind of strings from an external resource which I can't change:

```
["one item",0,0,2,0,1,"800.12"],
["another item",1,3,2,5,1,"1,713.59"],
(etc...)
```

I use the following code to explode the elements into an array.

```
<?php
$id = 0;
foreach($lines AS $line) {
  $id = 0;

  // remove brackets and line end comma's
  $found_data[] = str_replace(array('],', '[',']', '"'), array('','','',''), $line);

  // add data to array
  $results[$id] = explode(',', $line);

}
```

Which works fine for the first line, but as the second line uses a comma for the thousands seperator of the last item, it fails there. So somehow I need to disable the explode to replace stuff between " characters.

If all values would be surrounded by " characters, I could just use something like

```
explode('","', $line);
```

However, unfortunately that's not the case here: some values are surrounded by ", some aren't (not always the same values are). So I'm a bit lost in how I should proceed. Anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Comment: ' the second line uses a comma for the thousands', I see a dot separator...

Comment: is that data perhaps formatted as JSON? looks that way to my based on your example

Comment: @ka_lin What do you mean? See the last value, 1,713.59. Thousands seperator is a comma, decimal seperator a dot. :)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann ahhh obviously. I'll try json_decode, thanks! Will report back.

Comment: @dirk The original post didn't have a comma separator

Comment: @ka_lin with all respect, it did, check the changelog. However franz's solution solved my problem, so thanks all for looking into :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `json_decode` here since your input string appears to be a valid json string.

```
$str = '["another item",1,3,2,5,1,"1,713.59"]'
$arr = json_decode($str);
```

You can then access individual indices from resulting array or print the whole array using:

```
print_r($arr);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => another item
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 1,713.59
)
```